# How do I normalize a 2d list? (python)

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list that looks something like this: [[5, 4, -1], [3, -7, 8], [2, -9, 4]]
How would I go about normalizing all the numbers in the list to be decimals between -1 and 1

anything helps, thanks

Comment: Add them up and divide each number by the sum. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too certain how you want to normalize your numbers, so I am just going to assume that you want to add all the numbers in the list, and then divide each element by that sum.

Assume that

```
A = [[5, 4, -1], [3, -7, 8], [2, -9, 4]]
```

Running the below

```
[list(map(lambda x: round(x / sum(sublist), 1), sublist)) for sublist in A]
```

You will get

```
[[0.6, 0.5, -0.1], [0.8, -1.8, 2.0], [-0.7, 3.0, -1.3]]
```